# SES - Domain verification through Registro.br

Tags: domain, amazon-ses

I'm using the Registro.br DNS service. I've made a domain verification at SES which gave me the following code to put at TXT line:

/xYz24aNPG4mH2k+amyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=

But, when I try to put it there, the following happens:

/xYz24aNPG4mH2kamyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=

Then, the SES can't verify my domain, how can I solve this question?
OBS: the problem is at the plus (+) , which disappears from the TXT line
OBS2: this is not the real number generated

Comment: You are pasting this in the "Dados" field, yes?

Comment: Yep, they do a replace over the text that I input there

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the + sign...  ie, put + instead of +, like so:

```
/xYz24aNPG4mH2k\+amyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=
```

instead of

```
/xYz24aNPG4mH2k+amyZer8aDRdqcyQ9ZWZ2w1Fcn6w=
```

Comment: Didn't work, they do a replace over the text. So I can't escape the character.